# Динамическое обновление таблицы

Tags: ajax, php, html, javascript

Добрый день. Имеется таблица, в которой выводятся данные из базы. Так же реализован `js` скрипт, который по двойному клику дает возможность редактировать данные в таблице, по "Enter" сохраняет данные в базе и считает данные в последней графе, типа `"Итого"`. В базе данные обновляются, а в графе `"Итого"` данные не обновляются, нужно как то их обновить. Предполагаю что нужно использовать `ajax (long polling)`. Но как реализовать не знаю. Т.е. при изменении данных в базе, их нужно обновить в таблице. Так же проблема в том, что с приложением могут работать одновременно несколько пользователей. Просьба подсказать варианты решения данной проблемы, а так же в какую сторону смотреть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

есть много готовых компонентов - посмотрите JQGRID вот [тут](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

Comment: А еще варианты есть?)

Comment: а этот чем не устроил?

Comment: Мне кажется что придется все переписывать, что есть(( Хотя это не аргумент, но все же...

Comment: решать вам - но половина клиентского кода при использовании данного плагина уже написано)) писать придется только серверную часть